# UIApplication delegate must be used from main thread only - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-fabric

I am getting "runtime: UI API called from background thread: -[UIApplication delegate] must be used from main thread only
" runtime issue for Fabric initialisation line. Not sure how to solve it. Please help

Thanks

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self,Zendesk.self])
```

[image: Issue Image]

Comment: check once in your app where you used this `UIApplication delegate]` and `[UIApplication applicationState]`

Comment: I have checked and its no where used

Comment: then its the bug in Fabric,

Comment: `application.statusbarStyle` must be on main thread.

Comment: @Priyanka The issue is related to firebase which firebase version you are using ?

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasBhati Following are Firebase versions:-

- Firebase/Core (3.17.0)

Comment: @Priyanka please update to latest firebase version or install 4.2.0 version add pod 'FirebaseCore' and update pod will resolve your issue.

Comment: If you comment out that code, is that app working or still crashing ?

Comment: Normally, when you get that, you can tap on the item on the left (It looks like you have selected it.) and that will highlight the line that is a problem with a purple marker (not a yellow marker shown in the image.) If you can post the source to this file, so we can see the rest of the code, we may be able to find the real issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are trying to access the UI from background thread. Just call the UI change in main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   application.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
}
```

UI process are maintained under main thread.

Comment: I have Tried it but same issue @fAiSaL